# Given a vector, a, how can I scale another unit vector so that it meets with the line that is perpendicular to vector a?

Tags: math

I understand how to do this using right triangles: the length of my desired vector will be the magnitude of `vector a` divided by the cosine of the angle between `vector a` and the given unit vector. Once I find this value, I can simply scale the unit vector by this length.

Assuming that the dot product of the normalized `vector a` and the given unit vector is greater than 0, how can I find this length using only vector math? Below is a picture to help illustrate what I'm trying to do. I want the red vector, which will be a unit vector, to be scaled until it meets the white line that is perpendicular with `vector a`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start with the green vector **a** and the red unit vector **r**.

Normalize **a** to get a unit vector we'll call **k**:

**k** = **a**/|**a**|

Now project **r** onto **k** to get the component of **r** in the direction of **a**, call it x (which is equal to the cosine of the angle between **r** and **a**).

x = **r** · **k** = (1/|**a**|)(**r** · **a**)

Now we use similar triangles:

|**R**|/|**a**| = |**r**|/x = 1/x

|**R**| = |**a**|/x

**R** = |**R**|**r** = (|**a**|/x)**r** = (|**a**|<sup>2</sup>/(**r** · **a**))**r**